# web.xml to WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and I want to know if there is a way to configure 
error handler in the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter like it used to be in web.xml
I want to catch all my UsernameNotFoundException/401 and do handle it.

example:

```
<error-page>
<error-code>401</error-code>
<location>/SngErrorHandler</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
<exception-type>org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException</exception-type>
<location>/SngErrorHandler</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the javadoc of `AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer` (for Spring-Security 3.2.x), Spring security normally does this automatically for you redirecting to "/login?error"

If you want to redirect to another page and you are using login form authentication, you can do that by adding `http.formLogin().failureUrl("/SngErrorHandler")` in the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method of your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

This has to be adapted if you are using other authentication methods.

Comment: Hi, How should my SngErrorHandler should look like?

Comment: @orikoko Classically, in web.xml the error pages are simple HTML ones, so I supposed this was what you wanted. In the method I showed `SngErrorHandler` may be any URL (but it would be better if it was accessible without authentication ...). If it is not what you need, you should edit your questions to add any precisions.

Comment: Hi 
In web.xml the SngErrorHandler is not html, this is a servlet class that generating a response (String).